# Strange html formating after aligning text and image on same line

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I wanted to make my email as image, so I've put text and then email address as image. After that line goes another line, which is text and link on the same line.

But the problem is that for some reason second line (with text and link) is being formated with parameters on the first line, even though it is not on same div tag. I don't get it why it is being formated at all (when I delete first line and all formating for it, then www:link goes on one line as it should). I can only bypass it by using:

```
<br /> // or another spacings such as padding-bottom.
```

But I want spacings between lines to be minimal.

To make it more clear here is a screenshot, how it is looking now:
[image: Current state of my two html lines]

html code:

```
<div class="col3">
Email:
<img  class="image-align" src="http://safemail.justlikeed.net/e/931d68fcf4daa5643b0142bf34f3e4cb.png"/>
</div>
<div>
 www: <a href="http://www.test.com/">http://www.test.com</a>
 </div>
```

css styles:

```
 .col3 { 
width:140px; 
height:15px;
padding-bottom:10px;
 }

 .image-align {
float:right; 

  }
```

Also I'm using wordpress, but I have raw html plugin and tried raw tags and also disabled all wordpress formating, but it is the same thing.
Does anyone know what could be wrong?

What I want to do is second line should look like this:

```
www: http://www.test.com
```

Not like this:

```
wwww:
http://www.test.com
```

Comment: You need to be clearer, make an image of how you want it to look

Comment: Edit: Can't make it clear in comments.. I'll reedit my question.

Comment: is it because your image is set to float? maybe you need to give the second div `clear: right;`

Comment: There must be something else in your css affecting it, look at this working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vTcs4/

Comment: What could affect like this in css file? If there is no class that specifies div formating? Or is there any other specifiers that I should look into that maybe affecting in such strange way?

Comment: Could be the neighbors' divs and styling, or margin/padding IMHO.

Comment: I even deleted div for second line and it doesn't change anything. So I assume it has something to do with wordpress itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

***HTML***

```
<div class="col3">
  <div class="email">Email:</div>
  <img  class="image-align" src="http://safemail.justlikeed.net/e/931d68fcf4daa5643b0142bf34f3e4cb.png"/> </div>
<div class="sitelink">www: </div>
<div class="link"><a href="http://www.test.com/">http://www.test.com</a> </div>
```

***CSS***

```
.col3 {
    padding-bottom:10px;
}
.email {
    float:left
}
.image-align {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:5px
}
.sitelink {
    float:left
}
.link {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:5px
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nR6CP/4/)**

Comment: Well it kinda works, but if I try to let say put email image a bit to the left from text (to make space between text and email image), email image just goes on another line..

Comment: Oops. I changed wrong class. It works. I just can't seem to change spacing between these 2 lines. Is it possible to lower it a bit?

Comment: @oerp please check the update i.e add margin-left:5px to both image-align and link class. thanks

Comment: Its working and I already put that myself with padding-left. But I was talking about spacing between two lines, not inline spacing.
What I mean, there is bigger space between 'Email' and 'www', than it is on another lines on that page. How to reduce spacing between these lines?
There is no any spacing used to make it. I wonder is it possible to use minus spacing, to make these lines go closer to each other?

Comment: @oerp sorry i was outside. i will make your task within few minute.

Comment: just change the 'padding-bottom' property 1 2 3px vary as your need then  the line hide will minimize or maximize. thanks

Comment: I tried padding: 0px 0px -20px 0px;
But for some reason it can't be reduced. I know it has to be able to reduce padding bottom using minus. If I increase padding bottom it works and space between two lines increases, but it can't be reduced less than it is now for some reason. Is inline-block has something to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Assign the class `.col3` to the div, I think you may have specified a width for all div's earlier in your style sheet, and you need to overwrite it (make it as wide as the above div)

Comment: I haven't specified anything for div's in my style sheet. So it shouldn't be because of div. I tried to assign .col3 class to another div, but it didn't solve it. I don't get it why it looks like second line is in the first div, because if I make more space between lines, only then second line goes to normal or if I delete first line..

Answer (score 0):

Your width is the problem, try putting bigger value instead. Let us know how it works.

Comment: I tried putting bigger width, it just moved email image more to the left.
But it's working there: http://jsfiddle.net/vTcs4/1/
So it should have something to do with wordpress or style.css, I just can't seem to find what.

Comment: It is weird coz it runs fine in the fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/ocinisme/23UZW/] , maybe there is a clash with the nearby elements/CSS styling.

Comment: Yeah its weird, cause really works on jsfiddle.net. I checked all css classes that might be clashing, but it seems fine..

Comment: Probably I am too free so I hang out here, LOL. Try to put that text position as relative, and adjust it with top/left CSS syntax, see how it goes.

Comment: It doesn't fix the second line. It is fixed only, if email image is not on top of link. What I mean is if email image is more on the left than link. So that means for some reason image is blocking link (these two elements are conflicting in space..:))